# Getting CocoaPods Bug in Xcode : unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

**error:**

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   *unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker*

I have tried to remove "other linker flag", but that was not building properly. What should I do?

This error I got after installing cocoapod library and including into my project, previously my project was running fine.
Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

add this line:

`use_frameworks!`

to your Podfile and run pod install again.